# Silverlight: Set Items Widths in ItemsControl to Stretch

Tags: silverlight, itemscontrol, html

I've got an ItemsControl which fills from top to bottom, but I can't get it's child items to occupy the whole width of the ItemsControl:

[image]

I basically need to stretch the green bits to fill the width of the control (as shown by the blue bits).

I've tried things like setting the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the template item to `Stretch` and I've even tried binding it's `Width` property to the ItemsControl Width, but neither worked.

Should be a straight forward one, but it's something I just can't quite figure out...

Edit: here's the ItemTemplate (the whole thing is the ItemTemplate which itself contains an ItemsControl which is bound to a list of child objects):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#ddd">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18" Foreground="#bbb"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PlugIns}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,10" Tag="{Binding}" 
                                MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter">
                            <Border Child="{Binding Icon}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Your ItemTemplate would be helpful?

Comment: Ok Now I'm confused, why are you using a WrapPanel when you just want a straight list?

Comment: That's for the child ItemsControl which contains n items which need to wrap.

Comment: So what is the Panel type of the outer ItemsControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so as I continued to build the app up, I figured out how to resolve this. Essentially, when I changed the template of the `ItemsControl` to support scrolling, the items spanned to fill horizontally :)

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the `ListBoxItem` `HorizontalContentAlignment`, you do this by using a `Style` object in the `ListBox` `ItemContainerStyle` as follows:-

```
 <ListBox ....>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to use a ListBox as there's no need for selection