# Itemscontrol stretch silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Inside my itemsControl the item are not occupying the whole width of the user control. Am using DataTemplateSelector (manually written class) for selecting the type of template.

I checked the post [Silverlight: Set Items Widths in ItemsControl to Stretch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491769/silverlight-set-items-widths-in-itemscontrol-to-stretch) but its not working for me. Items are not automatically stretching and utilizing the full space. Please help! Thanks in advance

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource ="{Binding}" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                    
            <local:AddressFieldsTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" x:Name="addressTemplateSelectorObject">
                <!-- TextBox template-->
                <local:AddressFieldsTemplateSelector.TextBoxDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                                
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AddressFieldName}"  Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_TextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AddressFieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2"  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxLength="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:AddressFieldsTemplateSelector.TextBoxDataTemplate>
            </local:AddressFieldsTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Could you post a picture up on your question so we could see the problem in action?

Answer (score 0):

Items inside your datatemplate will always take up all available width due to the star width. The problem is most likely with the itemscontrol itself. Are you sure that the itemscontrol is not contained in a `StackPanel`, or auto-width `Grid` column. Is the `HorizontalAlignment` of the ItemsControl set to `Left` ?

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes ItemsControl is placed inside a grid. And that grid is inturn placed inside stack panel. I did not set the HorizontalALignment property for ItemsControl, so it should take default value. but not sure how will that impact the items stretch property?

Comment: Does your Grid have a width? And what is the orientation of your StackPanel?